# How do I find neighbors in Dijkstra's algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, lua, path-finding

How do I go about finding the neighbors of nodes? What makes a certain node a neighbor to another node? By the way I am writing the code in Lua

Comment: "What makes a certain node a neighbor to another node?" An edge between the two nodes.

Comment: What @DanielFischer said, but for a more descriptive answer give an example of how you represent your graph / grid (and if it is a square grid, do you allow diagonal moves?)

Comment: It is a three dimensional environment, I am trying to find the shortest distance between start and finish with node blocks

Comment: I think by neighbors he means all nodes which are connected..and using dijkstra you can get the shortest distance to every node and the nodes which have finite distance are your neighbors in that case..

Answer (score 1):

With A*, you define three things:

1. The cost of moving from one adjacent node to another
2. The distance between a given node and the goal node
3. The nodes adjacent to any given node

The first of those can be as simple or as complex are you want. When I'm doing simple grid-based pathfinding where all nodes are the same distance apart, I just return 1 all the time for very simple finding.

Dijkstra's algorithm actually covers the second of those, generally, by just returning 0.

But your question is about the third thing:

If you were doing this on a grid, you could just find the grid spaces that are the euclidean neighbours of the grid space you're looking at. That is to say, for grid space x2y2 the neighbours are x1y2, x3y2, x2y1, and x2y3 in euclidean space.

If you aren't dealing with a grid, I suspect the way that you will want to do is it to populate that sibling data for each node when you're placing them in the world or directly afterward and then store it in a list associated with that node. You might do that by calculating the distance from a node to every other node and finding the shortest ones or something like that. It can be very expensive but you'll only be doing it once at the very start so it should be fine if these nodes aren't dynamic.